# On odd perfect numbers $N$ given in the Eulerian form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Note: This question was cross-posted from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146557).

Preamble:  I apologize in advance if this particular MSE post would appear to be a bit of a *polymath* approach, I just had to put down all the details to present my argument for this particular math problem.

A positive integer $N$ is said to be perfect if $\sigma(N)=2N$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in Eulerian form if $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, where $q$ is prime, $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and prime powers are deficient, we have $q \neq n$ and $q^k \neq n$.

In an earlier version of the paper [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1090v1.pdf)), it was conjectured that the biconditional

$$q^k < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$

is true.  (Note that the proof of the inequation

$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} \neq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$

is trivial.)

Recently, an attempt to prove the said biconditional appears to have been completed in this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0906).

I present here the highlights of the said proof:

> > One direction of the biconditional is trivial:
> >
> > $$q^k < n \Longrightarrow \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$
> >
> > This is proved by noting that $I(q^k) < \sqrt[3]{2} < I(n)$ (where $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$), from which the following chain of implications follow:
> >
> > $$q^k < n \Longrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$$
> >     $$q^k < n \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{q^k}$$
> >     $$\{\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)\} \land \{\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{q^k}\} \Longrightarrow \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
> >
> > Therefore:
> >
> > $$q^k < n \Longrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \Longrightarrow \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

For the other direction:

> > The implication
> >
> > $$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} \Longrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$$
> >     can be proved, again by observing that $I(q^k) < \sqrt[3]{2} < I(n)$.
> >
> > Now, to prove the last implication:
> >
> > $$\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \Longrightarrow q^k < n$$
> >
> > we take an indirect approach.

First we show that:

> > If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form and
> >
> > $$I(q^k) + I(n) < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k},$$
> >
> > then $q^k < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$.

Similarly, we can prove that:

> > If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form and
> >
> > $$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < I(q^k) + I(n),$$
> >
> > then $q^k < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(n) < \sigma(q^k)$.

Observe that

$$I(q^k) + I(n) = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$

if and only if

$$\sigma(q^k) = \sigma(n).$$

Also, observe that if we assume

$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < I(q^k) + I(n)$$

then the biconditional

$$q^k < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(n) < \sigma(q^k)$$

will contradict $I(q^k) < \sqrt[3]{2} < I(n)$.

> > Therefore, the following inequality must be true:
> >
> > $$I(q^k) + I(n) \leq \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

It suffices to consider the case when

$$I(q^k) + I(n) = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$

which is true if and only if

$$\sigma(q^k) = \sigma(n).$$

This last equation, together with the inequality $I(q^k) < \sqrt[3]{2} < I(n)$, implies that

$$1 = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{\sigma(n)} < \frac{q^k}{n}$$

from which it follows that $n < q^k$. Thus, $1/q^k < 1/n$, which then gives, together with the equation $\sigma(n) = \sigma(q^k)$, the inequality

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}.$$

But this last inequality, together with $I(q^k) < \sqrt[3]{2} < I(n)$, is known to imply

$$n < q^k.$$

> > Consequently, if
> >
> > $$I(q^k) + I(n) = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} + \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
> >
> > then
> >
> > $$n < q^k \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}$$

*Now, here is the part where I am a bit unsure about logical solidity*:

Lastly, note that since

$$\sigma(q^k) = \sigma(n)$$

implies $n < q^k$, the biconditional

$$q^k < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$$

is *vacuously* true, under this case.

> > NOW HERE IS MY QUESTION (and this is also the main reason for this MSE post):
> >
> > I have been told that there is a *gap* in the last part of this proof.  As I
> >     myself am having a hard time spotting where that particular *error* is, would
> >     somebody be kind enough as to help by skimming through this argument and then 
> >     (after glossing over the details) give it either a *PASS* or a *FAIL*?

Comment: I do not see why $\sigma(q^k)=\sigma(n)$ would imply $q^k>n$. For example, $$\sigma(3^7)=\sigma(2863)=\sigma(3097)=3280,$$ but $$3^7=2187<2863<3097.$$

Comment: On the other hand, $$\sigma(5^3)=\sigma(99)=156$$ and $$5^3=125>99,$$ so $\sigma(q^k)=\sigma(n)$ does not imply any relation between $q^k$ and $n$.

Comment: However, in view of the inequality $I(q^k) < 5/4 < \sqrt{8/5} < I(n)$ (see [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) for a proof), we do have

$$1 = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{\sigma(n)} < \frac{q^k}{n}$$

from which it follows that $\sigma(q^k) = \sigma(n)$ *does imply* $q^k > n$ -- all of these of course *under the assumption* that there exists an odd perfect number $N = {q^k}{n^2}$.

Comment: Besides, please do note that for an odd perfect number $N$ given in the Eulerian form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, the following must be true:

(1)  $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$,
(2)  $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

Let me know if you have any more questions and / or comments, @Tharsis!  Appreciate it... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** (*January 30, 2015*)

Let $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form.

While $q^k < n$ does imply $\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$ (via $I(q^k) < I(n)$), $\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$ by itself **DOES NOT** imply
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$
Thus, the implication
$$\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \implies \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
remains unproven.

Similarly, while
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
does imply $\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$ (via $I(q^k) < I(n)$), $\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n)$ by itself **DOES NOT** imply $q^k < n$.

Thus, the implication $\sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \implies q^k < n$ remains unproven.

**Further Update** (*July 14, 2016*)

> Brown has released a [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) titled *A Partial Proof of a Conjecture of Dris* where he announced a proof for the inequality $q < n$, as well as a partial proof that $q^k < n$ holds "in many cases".
>
> If the inequality $q^k < n$ is proved, it will follow that the biconditionals
> $$q^k < n \iff \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \iff \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
> are also true.